# Reversing limits in Lebesgue integration

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I know that reversing limits of Riemann integration is possible by putting minus sign. My question is that there is a similar result for Lebesgue integral as well. For example,

$$
∫_{[a,b]}fdm=-∫_{[b,a]}fdm
$$

If b>a, I know that the right hand side is nonsense but.. I would like to know some similar results on it. I believe that there may have been some consideration on it among mathematicians. In fact, there are some comment in wiki as in the below but I don't know what it means. Any help would be appreciate.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration

Domain of integration[edit]
A technical issue in Lebesgue integration is that the domain of integration is defined as a set (a subset of a measure space), with no notion of orientation. In elementary calculus, one defines integration with respect to an orientation:

$$
∫_b^a f := - ∫_a^b f.
$$

Generalizing this to higher dimensions yields integration of differential forms. By contrast, Lebesgue integration provides an alternative generalization, integrating over subsets with respect to a measure; this can be notated as

$$
∫_A f\,d\mu = ∫_{[a,b]} f\,d\mu
$$

to indicate integration over a subset A. For details on the relation between these generalizations, see Differential form: Relation with measures.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, then we usually define
$$
\int_a^b f\,\mathrm d\mu:=\int_{(a,b]}f\,\mathrm d\mu=\int_\mathbb{R}f\mathbf{1}_{(a,b]}\,\mathrm d\mu
$$
for integrable $f$ and $a<b$. In this case we have
$$
\int_a^c f\,\mathrm d\mu=\int_a^b f\,\mathrm d\mu +\int_b^c f\,\mathrm d\mu\tag{1}
$$
for $a<b<c$ since $\mathbf{1}_{(a,c]}=\mathbf{1}_{(a,b]}+\mathbf{1}_{(b,c]}$. If we use the convention that
$$
\int_a^b f\,\mathrm d\mu=-\int_b^c f\,\mathrm d\mu
$$
whenever $b<a$, then $(1)$ holds for any choice of $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hence, you mean that we can write as $$\int_{[a,b]}fd\mu=-int_{[b,a]}fd\mu??

Comment: That depends on what you mean by $[b,a]$ when $b>a$.

Comment: In the Lebesgue measure theory, [b,a] is actually an empty set. Hence, all Lebesgue integrals on the set is zero. Therefore, there is no result related to reversing limits of integral in Lebesgue integral theory. In other words, whenever there is revering limits of integral, it means that the integral is Riemann integral. Am I right? The reason why I ask this is that there are integrals on paper I'm studying now but there is no mention whether the integrals are Lebesgue or Riemann. But it is important for me. Thank you

Comment: If the integral is denoted $\int_{[a,b]}$, then it's most likely a Lebesgue integral. I have, at least, never seen a Riemann integral be denoted like that.